# Using QuotedStr in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, delphi-7

I need to add another condition to my where cause below

```
SQL.Add('where (cmcl_bank_cleared is not null) AND ((cmcl_bank_cleared - check_date) >=:DaysParam)');
```

I need to also add

and (cmcl_bank_cleared <> to_date('01/01/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy'))

the problem is the single quotes

can i do the following?

```
SQL.Add('where (cmcl_bank_cleared is not null) AND ');
SQL.Add('(cmcl_bank_cleared <> to_date(' + QuotedStr(01/01/2011) + ', ' + QuotedStr('mm/dd/yyyy') + ')');
SQL.Add('((cmcl_bank_cleared - check_date) >=:DaysParam)');
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but check again you SQL syntax, because you are missing a `AND` and you must quote string literals or string variables.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using parameters for `:DaysParam`, but not for the date range? i.e `cmcl_bank_cleared <> :DateParamName);  ParamByName('DateParamName').AsDateTime := EncodeDate(2011, 01, 01)`

Comment: Gerry is right. Bind variables make code safer, and may make it faster too (the latter depeding on SQL usage)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use QuotedStr to build queries, but it's not the best idea.  If any of the input comes from a user, they could theoretically [enter strange things that would end up having unwanted effects on your database](http://xkcd.com/327/).  This is known as SQL Injection and is a serious security problem for a lot of websites.

The proper and safe way to insert values into the middle of a query like that is to use parameterized queries.  Look up the documentation on the Params property of your dataset to learn how it works.

Comment: I haven't used QuotedStr since learning how to use Params. It's a safer approach (and easier in the end), and you get to use things like AsString, AsInteger, and AsDateTime (very handy).

Comment: There is sometimes a reason *not to use* parameters. Datawarehouse-like queries (complex, with long execution times, and not often run) against databases using cost-based optimizers *may* get a better execution plan without parameters, because the optimizer has more data to analyze when hard-parsing the SQL statement, and *may* avoid to reuse a plan which could turn to be inefficient for the given parameters. Of course if not using parameters code must be "safe" against injection. There is no "one size fits all solution". A programmer must know his applications environment and data.

Comment: @ldsanson A well designed DB engine should take in account the parameters in both the request parsing and execution step. A DB acting like you describe (better execution without parameters) should be using a wrong design. Or the SQL query need to be modified. I'm quite sure modern DB optimizers are better than you expect for their optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work fine. Remember that `QuotedStr(S)` escapes any quotes in S by doubling them up. Since you don't have any single quotes in your string you are fine.

I presume you mean `QuotedStr('01/01/2011')` rather than `QuotedStr(01/01/2011)`. You've missed an `AND` too.

Answer (score 1):

`QuotedStr` just makes the code more complicated for the way you're proposing to use it. Instead, since you're hard-coding the date in the SQL anyway, just use the ordinary Delphi syntax for putting apostrophes in string literals by doubling them:

```
SQL.Add('(cmcl_bank_cleared <> to_date(''01/01/2011'', ''mm/dd/yyyy'')) AND');
```

You'd use `QuotedStr` if you had variables (or constants) that contained strings that you wanted to incorporate into the SQL. For example:

```
const
  ExcludedDate = '01/01/2011';
  DateFormat = 'mm/dd/yyyy';

SQL.Add(Format('(cmcl_back_cleared <> to_date(%s, %s)) AND',
               [QuotedStr(ExcludedDate), QuotedStr(DateFormat)]));
```